# Identificar un Event Listener - Firebase

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, firebase, xamarin

Tengo un `EventListener` que funciona de maravilla, pero planeo implementar otro mas y me seria de utilidad poder identificar cual es el `OnEvent` resultante en ese momento para que gatille el método que corresponda.

Me puse a revisar en tiempo de ejecución el resultado del listener con un punto de interrupción y el `QuerySnapshot` resultante en `data-Query-Id` me lo da (foto adjunta) pero no logro acceder a el, lo intente con `data.Query.Id` pero no reconoce Id.

```
public void OnEvent(Java.Lang.Object value, FirebaseFirestoreException error)
...
var data = (QuerySnapshot)value;
Alguna idea de como puedo acceder a el?
```

Este es el EventListener:

```
database.Collection("Usuarios")
.Document(gIdDoc)
.Collection("Notificaciones")
.AddSnapshotListener(this);
```

Adjunta

[image: Adjunta]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Id` es un propiedad de la clase `CollectionReference` que es una subclase de `Query`. Para acceder a él debes hacer un cast

```
var data = (QuerySnapshot)value;
var collection = (CollectionReference)data.Query;
var identifier = collection.Id;
```

Pero esto sólo funciona si la consulta es a una colección completa. Si tu consulta tiene algún filtro como `WhereEqualTo`, el cast fallará.

Como sabrás, el SDK de firebase que estás usando es una librería Java y está diseñado para que crees una clase anónima cada vez que necesites un listener. Así:

```
.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot value, FirebaseFirestoreException error) {...}
});
```

Pero C# no permite esto y por lo tanto, la única solución es crear clases nombradas

```
public class Example
{
    class Listener1 : IEventListener<QuerySnapshot> {...}
    
    class Listener2 : IEventListener<QuerySnapshot> {...}

    ...

    public void AddListeners()
    {
        database.Collection("Notificaciones").AddSnapshotListener(new Listener1());
        database.Collection("OtraColecion").AddSnapshotListener(new Listener2());
    }

}
```

De esta manera siempre sabrás que colección corresponde a cada listener.

Comment: Oye Sinner, disculpa, una pregunta relacionada. El EventListener me devuelve toda la colección al momento que se gatilla, seria posible, en caso de tener (digamos) 100 documentos leer solo los primeros 10? (Por ejemplo). Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Deberías leer la [documentación de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#java), es muy buena. No deberías tener problemas para entenderla ya que la sintaxis de Java es casi idéntica a C#. Sólo debes tener en cuenta como xamarin renombra los métodos.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho.